Form a results table view from splunk multiple logs
We have several logs that our application pushes to splunk. Out of which, we need to prepare a table with few standard columns with each column has it's own specific search criteria.
Below are the some of the sample logs.
Request Received
The below log will appear for every request received by the API.
{
  "Timestamp": 1722604623.878,
  "Attributes": {
    "cloudevents.event_id": "e340d8d0-9b33-4523-b870-5ca9cbc65b96",
    "deployment.environment": "dev"
  },
  "TraceId": "7f51f69d9a575e5ca9aba8d69ed3e665",
  "SpanId": "5b404c7c746df8c6",
  "SeverityText": "INFO",
  "Body": "Started processing the event"
}


Request Successful
This log will be recoded, only when the request successfully processed by the API.
{
  "Timestamp": 1722604623.976,
  "Attributes": {
    "cloudevents.event_id": "e340d8d0-9b33-4523-b870-5ca9cbc65b96",
    "deployment.environment": "dev"
  },
  "TraceId": "7f51f69d9a575e5ca9aba8d69ed3e665",
  "SpanId": "9017a2df177ba231",
  "SeverityText": "INFO",
  "Body": "Event published successfully"
}

Request Failure
A request can be failure for several reasons, based on the reason the Body attribute will differ. However, all the failure logs will have the SeverityText is either WARN OR ERROR. Also this is mutually exclusive with the success log.
Below is the sample log.
{
  
  "Timestamp": 1722605277.139,
  "Attributes": {
    "deployment.environment": "dev",
    "cloudevents.event_id": "ef410f62-62b4-4ad5-9464-902d829ea5e0"
  },
  "TraceId": "83f26927a04718955a6d7bee22eec2d9",
  "SpanId": "c3d856ec2b782973",
  "SeverityText": "WARN",
  "Body": "Found schema violations for event : [$.data.clinicName: does not have a value in the enumeration [Mayo Clinic, Appollo, Care]]"
}

From all these kind of logs, need to build the following table.



Event Id
Received
Published
TraceId




e340d8d0-9b33-4523-b870-5ca9cbc65b96
Yes
Yes
7f51f69d9a575e5ca9aba8d69ed3e665


ef410f62-62b4-4ad5-9464-902d829ea5e0
Yes
No
83f26927a04718955a6d7bee22eec2d9



Tried using appendcols like the query - index="my-index" Attributes.deployment.environment="dev" "Started processing the event" | top Attributes.cloudevents.event_id | table Attributes.cloudevents.event_id | appendcols Attributes.cloudevents.event_id [index="my-index" Attributes.deployment.environment="dev" SeverityText IN ("WARN", "ERROR")].
This is not a full query. Getting the error Unknown search command 'index'., so not able to proceed to create full query to full fill this.

You need explicit search in your sub-search code. [search index= ...]

@PM77-1. Thanks for your reply. Getting the error - Error in 'appendcols' command: Invalid argument: 'Attributes.cloudevents.event_id'

appendcols is almost always the wrong answer.  For it to work properly, both search must return the same number of results in the same order - something that rarely happens.  If the queries cannot be merged, try using append followed by stats values(*) as * by event_id to group them together.

I am not quite sure, what your criteria for getting a "No" for "Published" are. The current logic puts "Yes" if it has a "Body" of "Event published successfully", else "No". It is further unclear to me when an ID is recieved; so I assume that every event we see is received and thus it would always be "Yes". (If no event is received we would not know the ID, would we??) Please share feedback on this points or adopt them in the actual query by yourself.
This query the outputs your desired results:
First part makes this a run-anywhere example
| makeresults format=json data="[
{
  \"Timestamp\": 1722604623.878,
  \"Attributes\": {
    \"cloudevents.event_id\": \"e340d8d0-9b33-4523-b870-5ca9cbc65b96\",
    \"deployment.environment\": \"dev\"
      },
  \"TraceId\": \"7f51f69d9a575e5ca9aba8d69ed3e665\",
  \"SpanId\": \"5b404c7c746df8c6\",
  \"SeverityText\": \"INFO\",
  \"Body\": \"Started processing the event\"
    },
{
  \"Timestamp\": 1722604623.976,
  \"Attributes\": {
    \"cloudevents.event_id\": \"e340d8d0-9b33-4523-b870-5ca9cbc65b96\",
    \"deployment.environment\": \"dev\"
      },
  \"TraceId\": \"7f51f69d9a575e5ca9aba8d69ed3e665\",
  \"SpanId\": \"9017a2df177ba231\",
  \"SeverityText\": \"INFO\",
  \"Body\": \"Event published successfully\"
    },
{
  
  \"Timestamp\": 1722605277.139,
  \"Attributes\": {
    \"deployment.environment\": \"dev\",
    \"cloudevents.event_id\": \"ef410f62-62b4-4ad5-9464-902d829ea5e0\"
      },
  \"TraceId\": \"83f26927a04718955a6d7bee22eec2d9\",
  \"SpanId\": \"c3d856ec2b782973\",
  \"SeverityText\": \"WARN\",
  \"Body\": \"Found schema violations for event : [$.data.clinicName: does not have a value in the enumeration [Mayo Clinic, Appollo, Care]]\"
    }
]" 
| fields _raw
| spath 
| rename "Attributes.cloudevents.event_id" AS "Event Id"

Second part does the work
| eval Published=case(Body=="Event published successfully","Yes",true(),null())
| eval Received="Yes"
| stats values(Published) AS Published BY TraceId "Event Id" Received
| fillnull value="No" Published


When the log present, it's implicitly received. It would be a great help, if you can update this with dynamic query, instead of using a static data starting with | makeresults format=json data="[.

@ParameshKorrakuti well I do not receive your loggs, so I could only guess; probably your base query would be `index="my-index" Attributes.deployment.environment="dev"`` or so

Tested the query index="my-index" Attributes.deployment.environment="dev" | rename "Attributes.cloudevents.event_id" AS "Event Id" | eval Published=case(Body=="Event published successfully","Yes",true(),null()) | eval Received="Yes" | stats values(Published) AS Published BY TraceId, "Event Id", Received | fillnull value="No" Published | table "Event Id", Published, TraceId.
Getting the results. However missing the TraceId field for the logs which are Published = No.

I can't really assist you unless you provide more sample data! Do such events have a TraceId in the original data? It should not be lost in the query...

Logs from other API causing the TraceId to be null, updated the query to include only the required API and working fine.
